# MS Word: Searching key shortcuts for customization

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-office-2016

I'm trying to change the Windows key binding for "redo." One can change key bindings in `Customize Ribbon` -> `Customize`, but it's hard to find the one exact key binding one wishes to change in a list of hundreds of them. Is there a way to search the available key bindings for the one I'm looking for, either by the current key shortcut, or by the name of the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient macro which lists all commands and their assigned shortcuts. Use `View` -> `Macros` -> Choose `Macros in: Word Commands` -> Choose `ListCommands` in the list box -> `Run`.

Otherwise, there is a docs article describing all [Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Word on Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-on-windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2), and a [docx document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/8/FC8A61CA-8223-45F0-99F0-21B4AFFBCDCC/Word%202016%20for%20Windows%20keyboard%20shortcuts.docx) as well.